# r* expression NFA

Tags: nfa

I have found this image, which represents r* expression NFA.
My question is: there shouldn't be an arrow linking the second node to the third node? This way if I have a "rr" string, when the first symbol is read I get into the second node, but from there can't go anywhere because there aren't outgoing arrows.
http://imageshack.us/f/641/screenshot20111021at114.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked image implies a couple of assumptions.

- Arrows labeled "E" are implied to mean "epsilon transition", a changing state that doesn't modify the current symbol.  following such an arrow doesn't "consume any input"
- The rectangular region labeled "R" is implied to mean "An automaton accepting *R*".  if you reach the starting state on that region (the second circle from the left in the image), the boxed region will accept *R* for an arbitrary sublanguage.  *R* is used as a variable, just as it is in the base regular expression `R*`.  We don't see any arrows between the starting and ending states because we don't define what *R* means; it's variable, we could use anything.